# mongoid array of hashes, how to write form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a Rails 5 app, and I have a model that has an array of hashes:

```
field :addresses, type: Array
```

I want to build a form that lets the user add a dynamic number of addresses.  I tried this inside the form_for:

```
<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address| %>
    <%= address.text_field :line_1 %>
```

but this doesn't work. It renders the form fine but doesn't set or get the address attributes.

After reading a bit, it looks like you can't use fields_for for a ruby / mongoid hash.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Mustn't be only `f.fields_for :addresses do |address|`, why the extra block after that?

Comment: Have you considered using `embeds_many :addresses` instead? That still leaves you with an array of hashes in MongoDB but everything else would see an array of models rather than just an array of "whatever" so there'd be structure for things to work with.

Comment: @SebastianPalma that was a typo, i'll update, good catch

Comment: "It renders the form fine" - No, it won't. `g` is undefined here.